# test android application error

Tags: java, android

Now a day I'm completing tutorial and I found this type of error in testApplication.
what should i do?
It's simple HeloAndroidTest application.

Error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:239)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:87)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:263)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:185)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:373)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3210)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:966)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid
at com.example.helloandroid.test.HelloAndroidTest.<init>(HelloAndroidTest.java:13)
... 18 more
```

Comment: Yikes!!! Do one language at a time, not three!

Answer (score 3):

Hello from the future!

```
super("com.example.helloandroid", HelloAndroid.class)
```

is deprecated. You need to have a no arg contructor in your test that passed the activity in to the super thusly:

```
 public MyTest() {
        super(MyActivity.class);
    }
```

That is the cause and cure of this error.